# Style Triggered binding never release

Tags: c#, .net, binding, datatrigger

And a happy new year.

Here is my question, does a binding created in a style ever goes out of scope.

Let me explain, I have a textblock with a multi binding on values of two elements in a list "Names", a list of string in the viewmodel.

I acces those element by index with a magic string in the xaml (yikes, i know, i dont know how to do differently, if i set the binding on the collection, the itemChanged event doesnt trigger the binding...).

I need to get changes on the value and i dont really want to create any kind of accessor. I would like it to be all handled in the view.

```
<TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Text"
                        Value="" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsGroupedBy, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource  Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
                                 Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Text">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConcatStringConvertor}"
                                              UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
                                              Mode="OneWay">
                                    <Binding Path="Names[1]"
                                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource  Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}"
                                             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                                    <Binding Path="Names[2]"
                                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource  Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}"
                                             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsGroupedBy, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource  Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
                                 Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="0">
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
```

I set this binding in a style with a datatrigger on a "IsGroupedBy== true".
the textbox text is set to 0 if "IsGroupedBy== false".
It does work (when useBinding is true i got my two values concatenated in the textblock and it's "0" otherwise.

My problem comes now, the first time i set useBinding to true, the binding is created. From now on, if i change (typically i empty it) my list EVEN WITH IsGroupedBy TO FALSE, the binding gets evaluated;

I then end up with an argument exception on the Index out of range. (which is silent and the end user will never know, but its not really clean and perfomance oriented ...)

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 17 : Cannot get 'Item[]' value (type 'String') from 'Names' (type 'ObservableCollection`1'). BindingExpression:Path=Names[1]; DataItem='MainWindow' (Name=''); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String') ArgumentOutOfRangeException:'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: ...
```

I thought the conditional binding would solve this problem, it doesnt ...

Im open to any solutions (particularly if i can find a way to remove those Names[1] from the bindings)

PS: sorry for my english.

```
EDIT :
    public ObservableCollection<string> Names { get; set; }
```

EDIT 2 :
I tryed another approach, i use a priority binding like so :

```
<TextBlock.Text>
                <PriorityBinding>
                    <Binding Path="IsGroupedBy"
                             Converter="{StaticResource NotFalseToUnsetValueConverter}"
                             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource  Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}" />
                    <Binding Path="Names[1]"
                             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource  Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}" />
                </PriorityBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>


public class NotFalseToUnsetValueConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var groupBy = value as bool?;
            return (groupBy.Value == true)
                ? DependencyProperty.UnsetValue // evaluate next binding which is on array
                : "dont bind array"; // stop at first binding and dont check array  
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

But i got the same issue, the first time i evaluate the binding on Names[1] it somehow get registered somewhere.

And even if i stop being bound to the second binding any emptying on the list send the error :

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 17 : Cannot get 'Item[]' value (type 'String') from 'Names' (type 'ObservableCollection`1'). BindingExpression:Path=Names[1]; DataItem='MainWindow' (Name=''); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String') ArgumentOutOfRangeException:'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

EDIT 3 :
Here is the real binding :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="customGroupValueTemplate">
            <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=uxGrid, Path=ActualWidth}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <dxe:CheckEdit  Grid.Column="0"
                                Initialized="cbGroupSummary_Initialized"
                                Checked="cbGroupSummary_Checked"
                                Unchecked="cbGroupSummary_Unchecked"
                                Content="{Binding Value}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"
                           Margin="10,0,0,0"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Text="{Binding Path=(dxg:RowData.RowData).GroupSummaryData[0].Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                <TextBlock  Grid.Column="4"
                            Margin="10,0,0,0"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource GetPercentAsTextConv}"
                                      UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
                                      Mode="OneWay">
                            <Binding Path="(dxg:RowData.RowData).GroupSummaryData[1].Value"
                                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"
                                     UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                            <Binding Path="(dxg:RowData.RowData).GroupSummaryData[2].Value"
                                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"
                                     UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
                <ProgressBar  Grid.Column="5"
                              Width="100"
                              Height="10"
                              Margin="10 0 0 0"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <ProgressBar.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource GetPercentConv}"
                                      UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
                                      Mode="OneWay">
                            <Binding Path="(dxg:RowData.RowData).GroupSummaryData[1].Value"
                                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"
                                     UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                            <Binding Path="(dxg:RowData.RowData).GroupSummaryData[2].Value"
                                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"
                                     UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </ProgressBar.Value>
                </ProgressBar>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Plz notice that it's a template.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean IsGroupedBy instead of useBinding.
not pretty solution but you could replace `Binding Path="Names[1]"` by `Binding Path="Names.ElementAtOrDefault(1)"`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, unfortunately this does not work : `BindingExpression path error: 'ElementAtOrDefault(1)' property not found on 'object' ''ObservableCollection '1' (HashCode=21932166)'. ` **BindingExpression:Path=Names.ElementAtOrDefault(1)** `; DataItem='MainWindow' (Name=''); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')` I tryed to cast to observable collection in the xaml it didnt work either ...

Comment: could you add the declaration of Names inside the viewModel. And why do you use MultiBinding, you could use a single binding which take Names, and inside you converter you concat the two first element.

Comment: i updated the question, i could give u a sample project if u want it'd be easier i guess. There is a lot I left aside my main issue being how to prevent a binding to be evaluated on a condition

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use multibinding ?

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsGroupedBy, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource  Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Names, Converter={StaticResource FirstTwoListValuesElemToStringConverter}}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsGroupedBy, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource  Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="0"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

and for converter

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(string))]
class FirstTwoListValuesElemToStringConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string> names = ((System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>)value);
        if ((names != null) && (names.Count > 2))
            return names.FirstOrDefault() + names.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
        else
            return System.Windows.DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: Hi, ok so more details, the list is one created in a control (devexpress - controlgrid - GroupRowData.GroupSummaryData[ ] ). I cant modify the object in the list to fire a change and bind on the list. I have to bind on the value of the object in the list to see the changes. I compute a percent on two values of a row to show it in a progress bar in the group summary control. This array is empty when i dont group by the column.

Comment: i added the real binding in the question cf EDIT 3